# How do I inject a custom version of WebDataBinder into Spring 3 MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wrote a custom implementation of the WebDataBinder. In the future I'd like to enhance it so that it looks for an annotation on the class itself and figures out if it should be binding data to it or not.

How do I get this class injected into the Spring context in place of the WebDataBinder?

What I want is that if I run this code, my version of the WebDataBinder gets injected instead of the default Spring one.

```
@Controller
public class MyFormController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

My custom implementation of the WebDataBinder. It lets me exclude data binding by class instead of by method names.

```
    package com.companyname.spring;

    import org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues;
    import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    public class CustomDataBinder extends WebDataBinder {

        List<Class> disallowedClasses = new ArrayList<>();

        public CustomDataBinder(Object target) {
            super(target);
        }

        public CustomDataBinder(Object target, String objectName) {
            super(target, objectName);
        }

        public CustomDataBinder disallowClass(Class... classes) {
            Collections.addAll(disallowedClasses, classes);
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        protected void doBind(MutablePropertyValues mpvs) {
            if(disallowedClasses.contains(getTarget().getClass())) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("DataBinder will not bind class [" + getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName() + "] because it appears in the list of disallowed classes [" + StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(disallowedClasses) + "]");
                }
            } else {
                super.doBind(mpvs);
            }
        }
    }
```

## EDIT1

### First pass, having trouble with the AsyncSupportConfigurer

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = RootContextConfig.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAsync
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class RootContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>();
        addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);

        List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler>();
        addReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);

        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = new CustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.setContentNegotiationManager(mvcContentNegotiationManager());
        adapter.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());
        adapter.setWebBindingInitializer(getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer());
        adapter.setCustomArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        adapter.setCustomReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);

        AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer = new AsyncSupportConfigurer();
        configureAsyncSupport(configurer);


//All the methods called off of configurer are giving me errors because they have protected level access. I'm not really sure how they're being called in the code I copied this from.
        if (configurer.getTaskExecutor() != null) {
            adapter.setTaskExecutor(configurer.getTaskExecutor());
        }
        if (configurer.getTimeout() != null) {
            adapter.setAsyncRequestTimeout(configurer.getTimeout());
        }
        adapter.setCallableInterceptors(configurer.getCallableInterceptors());
        adapter.setDeferredResultInterceptors(configurer.getDeferredResultInterceptors());

        return adapter;
    }
```

## Custom RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

```
package com.companyname.dirtylibs.spring;

import org.springframework.web.method.annotation.InitBinderDataBinderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestDataBinderFactory;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter extends RequestMappingHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected InitBinderDataBinderFactory createDataBinderFactory(List<InvocableHandlerMethod> binderMethods) throws Exception {
        return new CustomInitBinderDataBinderFactory(binderMethods, getWebBindingInitializer());
    }
}
```

## Custom InitBinderDataBinderFactory

```
package com.companyname.dirtylibs.spring;

import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebBindingInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebRequestDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.method.annotation.InitBinderDataBinderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestDataBinderFactory;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomInitBinderDataBinderFactory extends InitBinderDataBinderFactory {

    /**
     * Create a new instance.
     *
     * @param binderMethods {@code @InitBinder} methods, or {@code null}
     * @param initializer   for global data binder intialization
     */
    public CustomInitBinderDataBinderFactory(List<InvocableHandlerMethod> binderMethods, WebBindingInitializer initializer) {
        super(binderMethods, initializer);
    }

    @Override
    protected CustomDataBinder createBinderInstance(Object target, String objectName, NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {
        return new CustomDataBinder(target, objectName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a simple task. Spring allows for a lot of customization, but, damn, this change is not fun.

You need to extend the [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) class and override the [following method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html#createDataBinderFactory-java.util.List-)

```
/**
 * Template method to create a new InitBinderDataBinderFactory instance.
 * <p>The default implementation creates a ServletRequestDataBinderFactory.
 * This can be overridden for custom ServletRequestDataBinder subclasses.
 * @param binderMethods {@code @InitBinder} methods
 * @return the InitBinderDataBinderFactory instance to use
 * @throws Exception in case of invalid state or arguments
 */
protected InitBinderDataBinderFactory createDataBinderFactory(List<InvocableHandlerMethod> binderMethods)
        throws Exception {

    return new ServletRequestDataBinderFactory(binderMethods, getWebBindingInitializer());
}
```

Instead of returning a `ServletRequestDataBinderFactory`, you'll need to return a custom `InitBinderDataBinderFactory` that returns your custom `WebDataBinder` instances.

This change means you can't use the default `@EnableWebMvc` or `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` configuration. That's because they use `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` by default, but you need to register your own class.

You can, however, override the `@Bean` annotated `WebMvcConfigurationSupport#requestMappingHandlerAdapter()` method and provide your own implementation to return your own type. Look into what that implementation does for hints.

Comment: @Jazzepi Another note, for the configuration, Spring MVC registers the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`  bean with  the id `requestMappingHandlerAdapter`, so you could just overwrite that bean definition with a bean of your own with the same name. I think that should be enough. You'll have to check.

Comment: Where did you figure out that Spring MVC registers that? The stuff that Spring does in the background adding its own stuff to the context is kind of a mystery to me.

Comment: @Jazzepi Looking at the source code basically. The `DispatcherServlet` looks for its configuration in the Spring context or uses default elements if it doesn't find what it expects.

Comment: Will work more this week. Some of the classes you are talking about only exists in Spring 4 :) Which is fine, I wanted to upgrade anyways :P

Comment: I think I followed your instructions, and it makes sense to me. The only problem I have is trying to deal with the AsyncSupportConfigurer which has some protected methods that WebMvcConfigurationSupport was somehow calling in its implementation. I'm not sure how that's possible.

Comment: @Jazzepi They're in the same package.

Comment: I'm going to bail on attempting to implement this any further. I really feel like I'm stretching the limits of what I should be doing anyways. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: overriding createRequestMappingHandlerAdapter in WebMvcConfigurationSupport is helpful:

 @Override
 protected RequestMappingHandlerAdapter  createRequestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
  return new MyRequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
 }

Answer (score 0):

A self-contained example by decoding the accepted response:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
  @Override
  protected RequestMappingHandlerAdapter createRequestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
    return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter()
      {
        @Override
        protected InitBinderDataBinderFactory createDataBinderFactory(List<InvocableHandlerMethod> binderMethods)
            throws Exception {
          WebBindingInitializer webBindingInitializer = getWebBindingInitializer();
          return new ServletRequestDataBinderFactory(binderMethods, webBindingInitializer)
            {
              @Override
              protected ServletRequestDataBinder createBinderInstance(Object target, String objectName,
                  NativeWebRequest request) throws Exception {
                ServletRequestDataBinder binder = super.createBinderInstance(target, objectName, request);
                //other default configurations
                binder.setIgnoreUnknownFields(false);
                binder.setIgnoreInvalidFields(false);
                return binder;
              }
            };
        }
      };
  }
}
```